# How to pass on the value to another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

I've done some survey with React/TypeScript and .NET-backend. I'm trying to return the season the survey has been done in depending on the start and endDate. My TS-interface looks like this:

```
export interface CycleModel {
  id?: string;
  surveyId: string;
  companyId?: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  emailLastSent?: string | null;
}
```

And my code looks like this:

```
import type {CycleModel} from "../../../../../utils/api/apiInterfaces";
import type {VFC} from "react";
import { View, Text } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

interface Props {
  date: CycleModel
}

export const FindSeasonByDate: VFC<Props> = ({date}) => {
  let season = "";
  const start = new Date(date.startDate).getMonth();
  const end = new Date(date.endDate).getMonth();
  if (start < 5 && end < 5) {
    season = "Spring";
  } else if (start > 5 && end <= 11) {
    season = "Autumn";
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {season}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
};
```

However, I'm not sure why I get this error when exporting to another component. The component I'm exporting to:

```
import { View, Page, Image, Text } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
import {FindSeasonByDate} from "./FindSeasonByDate";

export const IntroductionPage = () => (
  <Page object-fit="fill" size="A4">
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <Image
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523047840906-018758c5ffa1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3026&q=80"
      />
    </View>
    <FindSeasonByDate date={}/>
  </Page>
);
```

What do I pass onto the date={}???? Because date={date} is complaining that date isn't declared.

Comment: Have you tried to pass ``{props.season}``

Comment: Yes, however it is complaining that props isn't declared.

Comment: and if you pass props in IntroductionPage?

Comment: I did  "export const IntroductionPage = (props: { season: CycleModel; }) " and now it is complaining in the component that I'm exporting IntroductionPage to.  <Document>
      <IntroductionPage  season={??????}/>
      <CompanyResults automaticAnalysisResult={automaticAnalysisResult} />
      <CompanyStatistics automaticAnalysisResult={automaticAnalysisResult} />
    </Document>

What do I pass down here?